# SourceTree keeps using the same old user email even after i changed it

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I tried this:

```
git config --global user.name "XX"
git config --global user.email XXX@xxx.com
```

It still doesn't work! When I try to push in SourceTree, it keeps using my old user profile's email.

Help!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have *user.name* and *user.email* settings in your local repository that override the global ones.

Try running `git config user.email` to confirm this.

If this is the case, run `git config user.email XXX@xxx.com` (without the `--global` flag) to configure the correct email in the local repository.

Alternatively, you could also run `git config --unset user.email`. This will erase the *user.email* value configured in the current repository, and git will use the global value as the default.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set your global user.name and user.email set then SourceTree is probably using its own.
You probably dont have the Use global user setting ticked.
In SourceTree press settings (top right) > Advanced > user information and click the Use global user setting. Alternatively you can write in your own in the boxes provided.